# Convert timestamp from am/pm to 24-hour in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time, format

I'm using jquery timepicker. On user side, time needs to be displayed as am/pm format (10:30am or 5:30pm). I need to append that value to datepicker value.
For example, if datepicker value is 07/08/2015, final value should be 07/08/2015 17:30.
Problem here is in converting 5:30pm to 17:30. How to do it with javascript

Comment: I checked the jQuery TimePicker docs and it looks like you should be able to format the time in 24-hour time (with hours as 'HH').   http://timepicker.co/options/

Comment: that's for displaying the value to user, but the thing is that user needs to see am/pm format and in backend I need 24 hour format

Comment: I understand. I'm a big fan of using Moment.js if you can afford to add another library. Otherwise, can you share some code that shows how you are planning to use the data on the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own conversion function that converts time-strings with "pm" in them by adding 12 hours, like so:

```
var convertTimeStringTo24Hours = function(timeString) {
  if (timeString.match(/pm$/)) {
    var match = timeString.match(/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)pm/);
    var hours = parseInt(match[1]) + 12;
    var minutes = match[2];
    return hours + ':' + minutes;
  } else {
    return timeString.replace('am', '');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to convert from the 12 Hour system(hh:mm:ssPM/AM) to 24 Hour system then you could use the following

```
function timeConversion(s) {
    const timeString = s.toString()
    if (timeString.match(/PM$/)) {
        var match = timeString.match(/([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)PM/)
        var hours = parseInt(match[1]) + 12;
        var minutes = match[2];
        var second = match[3]; parseInt(match[1])
        if (parseInt(match[1]) === 12) {
            return parseInt(match[1])+ ':' + minutes + ':' + second;
        } else {
            return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + second;
        }
    } else {
        var match = timeString.match(/([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)AM/)
        var hours = parseInt(match[1]);
        var minutes = match[2];
        var second = match[3];
        if (hours === 12) {
            return '00:' + minutes + ':' + second;
        } else {
            return timeString.replace('AM', '');
        }
    }
}
```